# CakePHP 4.1 ORM many-to-many contain works one way but not the other

Tags: cakephp, orm, cakephp-4.x

I'm facing an odd issue where a many-to-many relationship allows me to contain in one direction but not the other. I've managed to boil it down to a one-line example. In a controller,

this works as expected: `$this->MarketplaceCategoryOptions->find()->contain(['Users'])->all()->toArray()`

while this throws: `$this->Users->find()->contain(['MarketplaceCategoryOptions'])->all()->toArray()`

and the error is: `Error: [RuntimeException] "_joinData" is missing from the belongsToMany results. Results cannot be created. in /application/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/ORM/Association/Loader/SelectWithPivotLoader.php on line 179`.

Here are the models:

`UsersTable.php`

```
        $this->belongsToMany('MarketplaceCategoryOptions')
            ->setThrough(MarketplaceCategoryOptionsUsersTable::class)
            ->setClassName('MarketplaceCategoryOptions')
            ->setForeignKey('user_id')
            ->setTargetForeignKey('marketplace_category_option_id');
```

and on the other side:

`MarketplaceCategoryOptionsTable.php`

```
        $this->belongsToMany('Users')
            ->setThrough(MarketplaceCategoryOptionsUsersTable::class)
            ->setClassName('Users')
            ->setForeignKey('marketplace_category_option_id')
            ->setTargetForeignKey('user_id');
```

The join table:

`MarketplaceCategoryOptionsUsersTable.php`

```
        $this->belongsTo('MarketplaceCategoryOptions')
            ->setForeignKey('marketplace_category_option_id')
            ->setJoinType('INNER');

        $this->belongsTo('Users')
            ->setForeignKey('user_id')
            ->setJoinType('INNER');
```

The setup appears fully symmetrical to me so I really don't understand how it's possible for these  two to behave differently. As far as I'm aware I'm following all cake conventions. I also have a bunch of other many-to-many associations just like this one in the same codebase and they work fine. I've also manually removed all cache from the `tmp` directory, just in case. Any ideas what could be the reason?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything obviously wrong with the shown code snippets. Maybe you have logic somewhere that modifies the query results, removing the join data property, for example a [**result formatter**](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/query-builder.html#adding-calculated-fields) (could be from a behavior too), but that's just a shot in the dark, it could be caused by all sorts of things.

Comment: Couldn't find either one of these happening, but it has to be something along these lines.  

Something interesting I noted while debugging is that when I truncate the contents of the join table in the database, the issue goes away. In the sense that calling `$this->Users->find()->contain(['MarketplaceCategoryOptions'])->all()->toArray()` stops erroring and starts returning a list of users with `["marketplace_category_options"]=> array(0) { }`.  So the problem arises only when actual data is being matched, otherwise it recognizes the association and doesn't complain.

Comment: If there's no join table entries to process, then it won't reach the logic where the error will be thrown, so that's to be expected. Maybe start with checking what exactly the data looks like in `\Cake\ORM\Association\Loader\SelectWithPivotLoader::_buildResultMap()`, namely the `$result` variable in the `foreach` loop. The data that it holds could give a hint at what's possibly processing it in a way that the junction property is missing.

Comment: Adding `debug($result)` in that `foreach`:

Finding `MarketplaceCategoryOptions` and containing `Users`, it prints an `object(App\Model\Entity\User)` which has `_joinData' => object(Cake\ORM\Entity)` with a `marketplace_category_option_id` and a `user_id` - all good.

The opposite, finding `Users` and containing `MarketplaceCategoryOptions` prints an `object(App\Model\Entity\MarketplaceCategoryOption)` with `'_joinData' => null`.

The exact same with another many-to-many works ok, e.g. `Users` containing `Teams` prints `'_joinData' => object(App\Model\Entity\TeamsUser)`.

Comment: So there's no other data in the entity that looks suspicious? Something that could allude to some kind of modification being made to the result set from somewhere? Like additional, dynamically added fields? If so, I would suggest to first try to set up the same association in a fresh new application, if it works, go back to your current app, remove all other associations, loaded behaviors, etc, to see if you can get it to work, and if so, walk backwards step by step until it fails again.